# redmineのall-in-oneインストーラを用いるとエラーが発生

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

redmineのall-in-oneインストーラを用いるとエラーが発生します。
解決方法がわかる方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教授お願いいたします。

インストーラ配布元
  [binami　インストーラ配布元](https://bitnami.com/stack/redmine)

インストーラ名　　
　bitnami-redmine-3.1.2-0-windows-installer.exe

環境
　windows 7
　64bit
　professional

---

```
    インストール後の処理を実行中に問題が発生しました。インストールが正しく完了していない可能性があります  
 実行中にエラーが起きました C:\Bitnami\redmine-3.1.2-0/apps/redmine\scripts\redmineini.bat  : C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.2-0/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rbreadline.rb:1097:in `<module:RbReadline>': HOME environment variable (or HOMEDRIVE and HOMEPATH) must be set and point to a directory (RuntimeError)    
    from C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.2-0/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rbreadline.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.2-0/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.2-0/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.2-0/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/readline.rb:10:in `<module:Readline>'
    from C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.2-0/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/readline.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.2-0/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.2-0/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.2-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/line_editor/readline.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.2-0/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.2-0/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.2-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/line_editor.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.2-0/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.2-0/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.2-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.2-0/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.2-0/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.2-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.6/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.2-0/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.2-0/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.2-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.6/lib/bundler/vendored_thor.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.2-0/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.2-0/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.2-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.6/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.2-0/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.2-0/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.2-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.6/bin/bundle:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.2-0/ruby/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
    from C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.2-0/ruby/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.2-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.6/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize': Could not find rake-10.4.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)    
    from C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.2-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.6/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
    from C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.2-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.6/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
    from C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.2-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:132:in `specs'
    from C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.2-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:177:in `specs_for'
    from C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.2-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:166:in `requested_specs'
    from C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.2-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.6/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
    from C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.2-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
    from C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.2-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.6/lib/bundler.rb:122:in `setup'
    from C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.2-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.6/lib/bundler/setup.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.2-0/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
    from C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.2-0/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
    from C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.2-0/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
    from bin/rake:14:in `<main>'
C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.1.2-0/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.9.6/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in `block in materialize': Could not find rake-10.4.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

以下　省略

Answer (score 1):

インストールしてみましたが特に問題ありませんでした。

環境変数の中に、エラーメッセージ中にある HOME、HOMEDRIVE、HOMEPATH などいずれかが設定されていない正しく動作しないようです。

私の環境ではHOMEDRIVE、HOMEPATHが設定されており、この2つがあれば大丈夫なようです。

追記：設定例を記載しました

```
HOMEDRIVE=D:
HOMEPATH=\Users\A-pZ
```

一度コマンドプロンプトからsetを実行して設定されているかを確認してください。
参考になれば幸いです。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうざいます。
echo "[\%homedrive\%]" %homedrive% 
echo "[\%homepath\%]" %homepath% 
で確認しましたところ、設定はされているようでした。

Comment: なるほど、では具体的に値に問題があるのかも知れません（あまり修正しないところだと思いますが。。）　設定内容を追記しました。

Answer (score 1):

本家のサイトに同じ事象事例が出ていましたが
試してもダメでした。

https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Troubleshooting#gem-commands-fails-if-home-maps-to-a-network-drive
https://community.bitnami.com/t/redmine-2-6-2-to-3-0-3-in-windows/31408/24

他のマシンで実行してみますと
動きましたので、今のところ他のマシンで動かすことにしました。

Answer (score 0):

> HOME environment variable (or HOMEDRIVE and HOMEPATH) must be set and point to a directory.

です